# Elastic aggregate on multiple value

Tags: elasticsearch

I've a Elastic index `Posts` where I've a nested field `Tags` then I've an index `Category` which also have a nested field `tags`.

Is there a way to find the number of `Posts` connected to each `Category` via `tags` ?

To be clear, for each category I need the number of the post that have at least one tags that the category has.

`PostA` has `Tag3`
`PostB` has `Tag2`
`PostC` has `Tag1`, `Tag3`

`Cat1` has `Tag1`
`Cat2` has `Tag2`, `Cat3`

So 
`Cat1` has 1 post
`Cat2` has 3 post (1 from `Tag2` and 2 from `Tag3`)

Comment: Could you post your mapping and some sample data, and an example of the result you expect? If your mapping is complex then a simplified version might be better, that preserves the structure you're asking about.

Comment: Given you have the data in separate indices, what about pulling all categories and creating one large query with multiple filter aggregations representing each category?  For example, one aggregation called cat1 would would essentially ask how much of the result set (all posts?) matches tag1 OR tag2 OR tag3 where tag1, tag2, tag3 are in category1, another called cat2 would ask how much of the result set matches tag4 OR tag5 where tag4, tag5 are in category2, etc.  This solution seems unfeasible with large number of categories.

Comment: I'm curious about the underlying reason for having categories in a totally separate index? Do categories just contain the category name and tags or is it some kind of more involved entity?

Comment: @Val I've other info in the "Category" index. This is a simplified version.

Comment: This index configuration and query requirement will not work in Elasticsearch, meaning returning documents based on conditions that involve another index. This works in relational databases world but it's a scenario Elasticsearch is not happy about. You either need to flatten the structure and combine both indices into a single one or find a way to use nested or parent/child fields.